# Verify check button is not available

Tags: java, selenium

I use this code to check button presence:

```
protected void validateButtonPresence(WebDriver driver, String buttonId, String name) {
        List<WebElement> resultList = driver.findElements(By.id(buttonId));
        if(resultList.size() == 0)
        {
            try
            {
                throw new Exception("Button " + buttonId + " is not found!");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to verify that button is not present. How I can modify the code so it will check that button is not present?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very close to what you are looking for since element presence and absence are the same logic just with the opposite sign.

```
protected void validateButtonAbsence(WebDriver driver, String buttonId) {
    List<WebElement> resultList = driver.findElements(By.id(buttonId));
    if(resultList.size()! = 0)
    {
       throw new Exception("Button " + buttonId + " is present!");
    }
}
```

You can also return Boolean value instead of throwing an exception, like this:

```
protected boolean validateElementAbsence(WebDriver driver, String elementId) {
    return (driver.findElements(By.id(elementId)).size == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write `validateButtonPresence` method, by name itself it says it's a validate method. A validate method should always return Boolean either validation fail or pass right ?

**Sample code :**

```
protected boolean validateButtonPresence(WebDriver driver, String buttonId) {
    boolean flag = false;
    try {
        if(!driver.findElement(By.id(buttonId)).isDisplayed()) {
            throw new Exception("Button " + buttonId + " is not found!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Button is displayed on the page.");
            flag = true;
        }   
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return flag;
    } 
    catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
        return flag;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return flag;
}
```

I believe you can have a more reliable method than this by introducing `ExplicitWaits`.